# AWS Which ECR image is running in my ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Is there any way to figure out which ECR imageDigest sha256-hash a particular ECS task definition is running? I want to understand wether my CI jobs works or not.

A [task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html) has

```
"containerInstanceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<aws_account_id>:container-instance/18f9eda5-27d7-4c19-b133-45adc516e8fb",
```

and

```
"containerArn": "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<aws_account_id>:container/7c01765b-c588-45b3-8290-4ba38bd6c5a6"
```

but when doing `aws ecr list-images --repository-name my-repo-name` I just get a bunch of imageIds which contains an `{"imageDigest": "sha256:45adcc..."}` which doesn't help me figure out which particular container an ECS-task is running.

Comment: I don't think you really want image id here. That has to do with docker image layout. http://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/. I think you want to focus on image tags.

Comment: You want to know what version of an image is running for a particular task? Is that correct?

Comment: yes, preferably given the sha256.